# Don’t be arbitrary

Tags: number-sequence

What’s the next number in the sequence? 
2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 10, ?

P.S
I’m new, so tell me if the question was too hard or too easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

> 5

because

> each number in the sequence is the lowest base number where the number of the term (first is 1, second is 2, etc) in that base is a palindrome.

Example:

> 1 = 1 in base 2 
>  2 = 2 in base 3 
>  3 = 11 in base 2 
>  4 = 11 in base 3 
>  5 = 101 in base 2 
>  6 = 11 in base 5 
>  7 = 111 in base 2 
>  8 = 22 in base 3 
>  9 = 1001 in base 2 
>  10 = 101 in base 3 
>  11 = 11 in base 10 
>  12 = 22 in base 5

Note:

> I solved this without OEIS, but OEIS has this sequence as sequence [A016026](https://oeis.org/A016026)

Comment: That was fast! Awesome!